# Virtualization software options for macOS

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop, vmware, virtualbox, games

I want to play Alto's Adventure for free on my Mac so I installed Windows 10 virtual machine on my Mac using Virtual Box, but Alto's Adventure crashes in Virtual Box even if it give the maximum amount of video memory 256 MB with 2D and 3D acceleration both enabled. I also have the guest addition installed. I tried Parallels desktop and VMWARE they both worked fine but the trial has both expired.

**I don't want to use bootcamp**

Comment: Do you mean the "trial" has expired? Virtualbox is free software so there are going to be things that just don't work. Also you have explored all three virtualization apps available for the Mac. The only other is WINE (commercial version is Crossover Office) and that lets you run **some** Windows programs directly in macOS. But you would need to check compatibility as it is more limited than the virtualization options.

Answer (score 3):

You're in luck. It looks like Alto's Adventure has a native Mac version! https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id1287752517?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

However, let's pretend you weren't so lucky, or you absolutely needed to play the Windows version. Virtualbox, unfortunately, has very limited support for 3D Acceleration, which is needed by most video games. This is why (among other things) Parallels and VMWare are able to charge so much for their paid solutions.

You can try [Wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php) (or normal Wine), which works for some games. If Wine isn't compatible, your only options are unfortunately to either:

1. Use Bootcamp
2. Use a standard Windows PC
3. Purchase Parallels or VMWare. (I'd recommend Parallels for performance)

Note that both Parallels and VMWare don't support DirectX 11 games, and incur a significant performance penalty. If either of these are dealbreakers, you have to go with options 1 or 2.

Sadly, running Windows software on macOS will always involve some level of compromise. If there was a perfect solution, developers wouldn't spend enormous amounts of money creating native mac versions.

Comment: Alto's adventure for mac is so expensive... It is almost the same price of parallels. It is overpriced.

Comment: It costs $10 in the US App Store, which is 1/8 (!) the retail price of Parallels, and you'll get better performance to boot. Regardless, that's life. Sellers set prices, and you can take it or leave it. *Shrug*

Comment: If you want cheap games you can download steam and only buy games that are 70-80% off - they have a huge selection, even for mac.

Comment: Steam have all my favorite games except alto's adventure

Answer (score 1):

I used BlueStacks app player to fix my problem, the only problem left is the sound is having some lag.